# What is Ruby's default GUI framework?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, frameworks, default

If I remember correctly Python ships with `Tk` as it's standard framework. What's Ruby's default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ruby uses Tk as well](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/ext_tk.html).

Answer (score 3):

Ruby ships with the tk libraries.  Also available are [fxruby](http://www.fxruby.org/)

is quite popular and [shoes](http://www.rubyinside.com/whys-shoes-grows-up-1014.html) was gaining some momentum until the authors [mysterious disappearence](http://www.rubyinside.com/why-the-lucky-stiff-is-missing-2278.html).  Of course there are Qt libraries available as well.

Comment: FXRuby is also part of the one-click-installer on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

There are quiet a few libraries. Most known are:
- tk (as mentioned earlier: http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/ext%5Ftk.html)
- gtk (http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/)
- fxruby (as mentioned earlier: http://www.fxruby.org/)
- qt (http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Ruby)

Shoes doesn't deliver a gui library. It is more like a cross-platform framework to build light-weight gui-applications. On linux it uses gtk-libraries.

There's a nice framework for building gui-applications: Rugui (http://rugui.org/). It is a framework for bigger applications and it copies the Ruby On Rails way of working. It supports an MVC design, gui & qt and Rspec & TestUnit. Worth looking at!

Answer (score 2):

The answer previously accepted is now obsolete.  Tk no longer comes automatically with Ruby, but must be installed as a gem.  There is now no default GUI for Ruby.