# Is there a default GUI library for Ruby 2.5?

Tags: ruby

For example, if I install Python 3, I can run a GUI code with tkinter without installing an extra library. Java has Swing.

Does Ruby have any GUI library by default?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Ruby's default GUI framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401633/what-is-rubys-default-gui-framework)

Comment: @Виктор That answer is obsolete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Historically, Ruby used to come with Tk, but now you have to install that as gem, so there is no longer a default.